# media family on device is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups, database-restore

I am trying to restore a .BAK in SQL server but get the following error:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
> The media family on device 'c:\glyn\JA.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I have tried restoring using 2012, 2008 and even 2005 but nothing works, I have used the following query and through the Tasks>> back up but nothing works, here's my SQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE JA FROM DISK='c:\glyn\JA.bak'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've read that the bak could be corrupt, it was sent to my by another developer on DVD who is working on the project.

Comment: This probably belongs at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Googling the error message gives multiple hits about restoring a SQL 2008 DB on a SQL 2005 server, e.g. [this one](http://www.sqlserverblogforum.com/2011/05/restoring-a-database-from-higher-version-to-lower-version-sql-server/). Even if it turns out that that isn't the issue, it would be very helpful to know what version and edition of SQL Server the backup came from, and which ones you are restoring it on.

Comment: I dont know what edition, Ill ask